# Disable Next button in Elementor Forms multi-step

Tags: javascript, elementor

I'm creating a multi-step form using Elementor and would like to control when the Next button can be pressed (aside from using 'required' fields). The problem is that my code to disable the button does not seem to affect the button at all - it seems like the Elementor JavaScript for FormSteps is affected on the button after my code.

How can I play nicely with Elementor's code to interrupt the Next function until I've evaluated certain conditions to the true?

This is the code I have to disable the Next button:

```js
(function( $ ){
    'use strict';

    $( window ).on( 'elementor/frontend/init', function(){
        elementorFrontend.hooks.addAction( 'frontend/element_ready/form.default', function($scope){
            $scope.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
        });
    });
})( jQuery );
```

The code runs but the disabled attribute does not appear to be applied. I have also tried changing the class, on both the button and the wrapper elements, and adding onClick event handlers... none of it works.

Comment: Yes, that's what seems to happen. It does run, and then Elementor's code modifies it.